Can I cover a ceiling drywall with drywall?
I have a popcorn ceiling that was poorly installed, before I got the place. My question is, can I just scrape and cover it with another layer? Stagger joints on the old work, big sheets,add some lighting, etc.   The original has a few 1'x1' pieces, because, you know, they didn't want to waste anything.

Short answer, yes.  This is a cheaper option than tearing everything down from scratch.  Use longer fasteners.  If you have crown molding, you will have to remove it and reinstall after the new ceiling is in place because the ceiling will be slightly lower.

Check around and ask some neighbors.  Call some drywall contractors and see if they offer popcorn removal.  In my area we have services that will remove the popcorn carefully for $1.00/sq ft.  Then you only need to prime and paint.

I put that popcorn up, I am gonna take it down. It will also give me a simple way to get wiring up there for LED lighting. Thanks.

You sure can. It's done all the time to cover up bad, old ceilings or just to add an additional sound barrier from the upstairs noise. Care should be taken to use longer drywall screws and to hit all the rafters. You'll need longer screws for attaching any light fixtures in the ceiling and or will need junction box extenders.

By code, screws must penetrate at least 5/8 in to the wood. R702.3.5.1Screw fastening.
Screws for attaching gypsum board and gypsum panel products to wood framing shall be Type W or Type S in accordance with ASTM C1002 and shall penetrate the wood not less than 5/8 inch (15.9 mm).
